# Getting Data Locally from an Snowpark DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does df.collect() data into local memory? Is this the best approach to load data locally? Are there any tips or best practices to consider in snowpark?

Answer (score 0):

Yes

[df.collect()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.collect) brings all the data that the DF represents into the client as a single list  of Row objects.

I also found that it is possible to use [to_local_iterator](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.to_local_iterator)() instead of collect() if the data that the DataFrame represents is large